# Counting and Symmetry

Tags: combinatorics, symmetry

The digits $1,2,3,4$ and $5$ can be arranged to form many different $5$-digit positive integers with five distinct digits. In how many such integers is the digit $1$ to the left of the digit $2$? (The digits 1 and 2 do not have to be next to each other.)

**Case 1:** 2 is in the second spot

We get $3!=6$ ways.

**Case 2:** 2 is in the third spot

We get $4\cdot2=8$ ways.

**Case 3:** 2 is in the 4th spot

We get $3\cdot4=12$ ways.

**Case 4:** 2 is in the last spot.

We get $4!=24$ ways.

Thus, the probability should be $\frac{6+8+12+24}{5!}=\frac5{12}.$

Is this correct?

Comment: Case 1 and 4 are correct, but case 2 should be $2\cdot3!$, and case 3 should be $3\cdot3!$, because no matter where you put the $1$, you still got $3!$ ways to rearrange the rest of the numbers.

Comment: You titled and tagged this with "Symmetry" so you likely got that word from somewhere close to the source of the problem.  It's inclusion should have been a huge hint as to an easy way to proceed.  Keep an eye out for such hints in the future.

Answer (score 2):

A different way is $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to pick 2 slots for 1 and 2, where 1 is always the left one, and $3!$ ways to arrange the rest of the numbers in their own 3 slots. So total number of cases is
$$
\binom{5}{2} \cdot  3! = 10 \cdot 6 = 60.
$$

This also changes the probability:
$$
\frac{60}{5!} = \frac{60}{120} = \frac12 = 50 \%.
$$

---

Now that you see a tedious way to find it's $50\%$, note there is an obvious symmetry. In the set of all $5!$ permutations, the number of cases where $1$ precedes $2$ is by symmetry the same as number of cases where $2$ precedes $1$, so the result must be $1/2$.

Comment: I'm sorry, 1/2 is incorrect.

Comment: @Fleccerd  This answer is correct.  Why do you think it is incorrect?

Comment: @Fleccerd The only way that $1/2$ can be incorrect is because you are asking the wrong problem.  If we were talking about probabilities of having selected such a permutation, it is $1/2$.  If we were talking about the *count* of how many such five-digit integers satisfying these conditions there are that would be *half of the total*, i.e. $5!/2=60$.  Don't over-enthusiastically give probability answers to counting questions.  Otherwise, this answer is very definitely correct.  It is such an incredibly common first-semester combinatorics problem.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I forgot it was just a counting problem!